# (Pallindrome checker) [LEETCODE problem] I know I'm commiting some minor mistake but i don't know what it is

Tags: string, c++11, palindrome

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        getline(cin,s);
                bool answer;
                vector<int>l;
                vector<int>r;
                for(auto i=0;i<s.size();i++){
                    char c = s[i];
                    l.push_back(c);
                }
                for(auto i=s.size()-1;i<s.size();i--){
                    char a = s[i];
                    r.push_back(a);
                }
                for(auto i=0;i++;){
                    if(l[i]==r[i]) answer = true;
                    if(l[i]!=r[i]) answer = false;
                }
                return answer;
    }
};
```

I was expecting it to work fine but i think i am commiting some logical error while writing bool datatype.

the output in vscode is just blank output.

This program has cleared 2 testcases out of 3 in leetcode compiler.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that creates output.

Comment: What is the `getline` call for? Supposedly the input is the string passed *to* your function, you're not supposed to read it yourself.

Comment: As for the palindrom check, it's possible to do with only a single loop. I suggest you use a pen and some paper to try and figure it out.

Comment: The second loop is clearly wrong semantically as pointed out by a now deleted comment, although it "works" due to wrapping of `unsigned`, it is very confusing.

Comment: Before trying to submit your code for an online judge, *run your own tests*. You will learn more things faster this way.